# Java XMLEncoder, XMLDecoder, and UTF-8

Tags: java, xml

I have some code that encodes a map as XML, and later decodes this XML. It works as expected when the map values only have ASCII characters, otherwise it crashes. How can I make it work with Unicode characters? Keep in mind that I have legacy data that's encoded using this scheme, so switching to a totally different encoding method is not an option.

```
String firstName = "Влади́мир";
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("firstName", firstName);
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(outputStream);
encoder.writeObject(map);
encoder.close();
String serialized = outputStream.toString("UTF-8");
System.out.println(serialized); // output looks OK
XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(new StringInputStream(serialized));
Map<String, Object> mapOut = (Map<String, Object>) decoder.readObject(); // exception!
```

Error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x12) was 
found in the element content of the document.
Continuing ...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
  at com.sun.beans.ObjectHandler.dequeueResult(ObjectHandler.java:139)
  at java.beans.XMLDecoder.readObject(XMLDecoder.java:206)
```

Comment: Does your XML have the standard prolog, like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`? Did you look closer (as with `hexdump`) at your console output?

Comment: Does your XML have the standard prolog, like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`? Did you look closer (as with `hexdump`) at your console output?

Comment: Yes, I did have the XML prefix. The whole problem seems to have been on the decoding end - see Vineet's response. When I stopped using `com.sun.xml.bind.StringInputStream` to read the XML, it worked.