# How to decode special characters using XMLDecoder in java

Tags: java, special-characters, indexoutofboundsexception, decoding, xml-encoding

My string contains special characters (eg: Ã?tÃ¸kiligar) and when decoding it using XMLDecoder it throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Is there anyway to change the decoding format to another format(ISO-8859-1) than UTF-8?

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at java.beans.XMLDecoder.readObject(Unknown Source)`

Comment: XMLDecoder works on some kind of InputStream. Change that to an input where you can set the encoding to ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Possibly related (check comments): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492710/java-xmlencoder-xmldecoder-and-utf-8

Comment: The exception is thrown, if the input stream contains no objects. Are you sure you are reading from a document which was created using `XMLEncoder`? Please add the code which reads the input.

Comment: Previously I used XMLDecoder(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()))). Then when I used XMLDecoder(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8")))) it worked. @RalfRenz thanks your answer helped.